# How to get better advisors?

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

I am currently overflowing with money as the Ottomans through trade and tax income from my many provinces, but to keep up with the large European nations I have a constant need for more [monarch power](http://eu4wiki.com/Monarch_power) (administrative, diplomatic and military points).

As far as I know the best way to actively increase my monarch point income is by hiring better advisors.

As money is not an issue, I could easily hire lvl 3 advisors in all categories, but unfortunately the candidates I get often are only lvl 1 or lvl 2.

**Is there a way to influence the candidates for advisor slots to become better? (i.e. expensive level 3 advisors)** I know this is random to a large degree and that you can get an additional advisor slot through ideas, but I am looking for any way to boost the quality of the candidates.

Comment: Don't think this would actually work, but will a new advisor spawn every time you hire one? If so, and money is no issue, you could keep hiring/firing lvl 1 advisors, untill a lvl 3 advisor appeared.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not wrong, you can get more available advisors through idea paths.

For example, the economic path opens one advisor slot :

[image: Centralization]

So does the administrative one.

[image: Administrative]

With the centralization bonus (from the economic path), I can choose from 4 different advisors :

[image]

And this for each type of advisor.

That should help you to get better advisors.

Comment: Other ways to get additional advisors include becoming emperor or papal controller.

Comment: "I know . . . that you can get an additional advisor *slot* through ideas, but I am looking for any way to boost the *quality* of the candidates." [emphasis mine]

Comment: Yes, you're right, I missed that one.

Answer (score 1):

Have a lot of money.  From my experience your available advisor "level" IE cost is dependent on how much money you have available.

If your poor you will likely only have 2 level 1, and 1 level 2 advisor.  IF your filthy rich you will likely get at least 1 level 3 advisor available.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

With the Cossacks expansion, you can have each estate provide you with a level 3 advisor (at the cost of loyalty if my memory serves me right) which will cost half the price per month (9 ducats instead of 18).